# updating column values in pandas based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to update the column value based on these conditions

```
i. if score > 3, set score to 1.
ii. if score <= 2, set score to 0.
iii. if score == 3, drop that row.
```

Score has the values between 1 to 5

I have written the following code, but all the values is being changed to 0.

```
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] > 3, 'Score'] = 1
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] <= 2, 'Score'] = 0
reviews.drop(reviews[reviews['Score'] == 3].index, inplace = True)
```

Please point out the mistake am doing in this.

Comment: reviews['Score'].dtype = int32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is logic problem:

```
reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Score':range(6)})
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
```

If set all values higher like `3` to `1` it working like need:

```
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] > 3, 'Score'] = 1
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      1
5      1
```

Then all vallues without `3` are set to `0`, so also are replaced `1` from `reviews['Score'] > 3`:

```
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] <= 2, 'Score'] = 0
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      3
4      0
5      0
```

Last are removed `3` rows and get only `0` values:

```
reviews.drop(reviews[reviews['Score'] == 3].index, inplace = True)
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      0
2      0
4      0
5      0
```

---

You can change solution:

```
reviews = pd.DataFrame({'Score':range(6)})
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
```

First removed `3` by filter all rows not equal to `3` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
reviews = reviews[reviews['Score'] != 3].copy()
```

And then are set values to `0` and `1`:

```
reviews['Score'] = (reviews['Score'] > 3).astype(int)
#alternative
reviews['Score'] = np.where(reviews['Score'] > 3, 1, 0)
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      0
2      0
4      1
5      1
```

EDIT1:

Your solution should be changed with swap lines - first set `0` and then `1` for avoid overwrite values:

```
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] <= 2, 'Score'] = 0
reviews.loc[reviews['Score'] > 3, 'Score'] = 1

reviews.drop(reviews[reviews['Score'] == 3].index, inplace = True)
print (reviews)
   Score
0      0
1      0
2      0
4      1
5      1
```

Comment: Do you mean `reviews = reviews[...].copy()`? Also, your code seems to be equivalent to OP's one, which should be perfectly fine. I think the issue is something else.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Thanks, it seems correct, but only seems, edited answer.

Comment: Great answer with explanation